# How do I click on a <i> tag under a <li> element of a <ul> list?

Tags: c#, list, selenium

How do I click a i tag that is under a li tag?

The "li" would be the options displayed in this "ul" list, and the "i" is the checkbox of each "li" I need to click

What I tried:

```
IList<IWebElement> dropDownMenu = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.col-lg-6:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(1)"));
IList<IWebElement> selectmember = dropDownMenu[0].FindElements(By.TagName("i"));
var count = selectmember.Count;
if (count > 0)
      {
       selectmember[0].Click();
      }
```

HTML code:

```
<li ng-repeat="s in servicePlans | orderBy:'name' | filter:filterServicePlans" ng-if="!($index % 2)" style="font-size: 12px; margin: 3px 0; min-height: 24px; list-style-type: none;" class="crop-long-text ng-scope">
    <a href="javascript:;" style="text-decoration: none" class="font-dark" ng-click="clickService(s)">
         <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" ng-class="{ 'fa-square-o': s.checked == false, 'fa-check-square-o': s.checked, 'fa-minus-square-o' : s.checked == null }" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>
                                        <span class="ng-binding">To-Do (BPOS_S_TODO_1)</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sGet directly to needed i element you can with this code

```
IWebElement selectmember = Driver.FindElement.By.XPath(".//ul[what attributes it have place here]//li[order number]//i")
```

Get an array of i elements to iterate click you can with this code

```
IWebElement[] selectmembers = Driver.FindElements.By.XPath(".//ul[attributes]//li//i").ToArray();
foreach(IWebElement q in selectmembers)
q.Click();
```

Comment: This is not standard C# Selenium code... I don't know what this is unless it's some custom C# code. Also, the `.` at the start of your XPath is not needed. That's only used if you want to start searching from a specific element, e.g. `Driver.FindElement(By.Id("myId")).FindElement(By.XPath(".//div"));`